# Comparing monthly data with different number of data points

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling

Every day I monitor some value M which comes from an unknown distribution. Depending on the month I collect a different number of measurements of M. My data looks like this, (N is the number of samples in given month, M is a mean of daily measurements)

Month 1, M=100, N=10000
Month 2: M=300, N=100
Month 3: M=102, N=15000
Month 4: M=99, N=13000
Month 5: M=101, N=12000

When I try to plot the data Month 2 raises questions but given there are only 100 data points I will not be able to do any reasonable investigation.

Is there a way to produce some kind of confidence interval over the monthly values that is dependent on the number of data points?

I tried to bootstrap confidence interval per each month but the results were so tight for Month 2 (-/+ 5) that they were not useful

Comment: I'm wondering, is there are seasonality issue here? Is seasonality part of the analysis?

Comment: Let assume there is no seasonality here.